# Que instrucción utilizar en un .bat para cerrar un .jar en especifico, si hay varios .jar ejecutandose

Tags: java, .bat

Esta seria la instrucción que tengo en mi archivo .bat, para cerrar el .jar que ejecuto, pero cuando tengo otro .jar ejecutándose, también me lo cierra.

```
C:
cd \enl_ba_fro\NeCore
TASKKILL /F /IM javaw.exe
```

y esta otra instrucción no me funciona ya que le quiero especificar el .jar en especifico.

```
C:
cd \enl_ba_fro\NeCore
TASKKILL /F /IM java -jar ne-core.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Podría servir algo como wmic

```
wmic PROCESS Where "name Like '%java.exe%' AND CommandLine like '%ne-core.jar%'" Call Terminate
```

la otra opción es arrancar los procesos con

```
start "MyProgramName" java java-program..
```

para poder luego hacer

```
taskkill /fi "MyProgramName"
```

Ese `/FI` es poderoso, uno puede filtrar por WindowName (el nombre que tiene la ventana del proceso) y otros parámetros...